# How to Uninstall a Magento 2 Module from Another Module's Install Script?

Tags: php, magento

Hello Magento Experts,

I'm currently developing a Magento 2 module that comes in two versions: a free trial version with limited functionality, and a full-featured paid version. As I understood, the only way I can do that is to basically list two separate modules on the marketplace. I want to make it so that when the paid version is installed, it automatically uninstalls, or at least disables the free trial version if it's present.

How can I do that programatically, for example in the `InstallData.php` or something like that?